# conversion of java milliseconds to readable time in Access db

Tags: ms-access, milliseconds

How can I update a column in a table in an access db, so the time isn't given in java milliseconds (e.g. change "1395751603796" to "25.03.2014 12:46" or something similar)?

Edit for clarification: 
The type of the column is Text, but I can create a new column of the type Date/Time. I imported values for further use (e.g. grouping by month etc.), and the values just happened to be milliseconds. I'd prefer to just update the table (with > 400,000 rows) in Access.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to provide more details: **(1)** It sounds like the millisecond values are in an existing column. What is the column's type (Text? Decimal?) **(2)** Can you create a new field in the table to hold "real" Access Date/Time values? **(3)** Do you want to use Java to convert the values, or do you want to do the conversion in Access itself (and the existing values just happen to be milliseconds as produced by Java)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a table named [msTable] with a Text field named [milliseconds] and a Date/Time field named [DateTimeField]

```
ID  milliseconds   DateTimeField
--  -------------  -------------------
 1  1395751603796
```

the query

```sql
UPDATE msTable 
SET DateTimeField = DateAdd("s",Round(CDbl(milliseconds)/1000,0),DateSerial(1970,1,1))
```

results in

```
ID  milliseconds   DateTimeField
--  -------------  -------------------
 1  1395751603796  2014-03-25 12:46:44
```